# How do I select all opportunities under an Account?

Tags: trigger, opportunity, account

I wish to select all opportunities on an Account, how do I go about it?

I have tried this:

```
trigger StatusTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) {  
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Opportunity op : Trigger.new) {
   accountIds.add(op.AccountId);
}

Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]);
Opportunity[] opp = [SELECT Opportunity FROM Account WHERE id IN: accountIds];

for(Opportunity oppo : opp) {


}
}
```

But I get the error "Opportunity does not exit" which is an error from this line `Opportunity[] opp = [SELECT Opportunity FROM Account WHERE id IN: accountIds];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
trigger StatusTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete) {  
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();

for (Opportunity op : Trigger.new) {
   accountIds.add(op.AccountId);
}

for(Account a : [select id, (select id from opportunities) from account where id in: accountIds]) {
    for(Opportunity opp : a.opportunities) {
        system.debug(opp.id);
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second query isn't doing what you think it's doing.

```
[SELECT Opportunity FROM Account WHERE id IN: accountIds]
```

Will try to query for the `Opportunity` field on the `Account` object, which is part of what Salesforce is complaining about (there is no field called `Opportunity` on `Account`). The other issue is that you're querying for `Accounts`, and are trying to put them into a list of `Opportunity`.

The query you want is this

```
[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds]
```

This would give you all `Opportunity` records related to an `Account` record that you got from the `Opportunity` records that are being triggered. This, however, isn't broken down into which Opportunities are under what Account.

To get that, you could use a parent-child subquery which would look like this

```
[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]
```

Answer (score 2):

[SELECT Opportunity FROM Account WHERE id IN: accountIds]; --> this select query may return more than one opportunity.

So create a reference, your code "Opportunity[] opp" as a list and try to continue your rest.
Eg: "List <> opp = [];"

I am surprised why you want to have a loop, map, set etc..
If you want to select list of opportunity, just take the account id related to the opportunity you are referring and pass the id in where clause.